# Is there any way to control ko.toJS / ko.toJSON?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

```
var mappingSetting = {
  'user' : {
      create: function(options.data){
          options.data.isActive = options.data.isActive == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
          options.data.startDate = $.datepicker.format('dd/MM/yy', options.data.startDate)
          return options.data;
          }
     }
};

var viewModel = {};

$.ajax({
   url: '/api/users/GetAll',
   .....
   success: functions (data) {
       viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingSetting);
       ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
   },
});

$("#savebtn").click(function(){
    var dataToSave = ko.toJS(viewModel);
    // ajax call to save
});
```

ajax result

```
[{username: 'users1', isActive:1, startDate:'2001-03-22T00:00:00CET'}, {username: 'users2', isActive:0, startDate:'2008-03-22T00:00:00CET'}]
```

i have to show Yes / No on the base of isActive but while saving i have to change that back to 0 / 1.

i have many fields and also date (local culture format).

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better served to keep isActive as a boolean and either use a computed function, or a custom binding handler, to show "Yes"/"No" given the value of isActive.

**Custom Binding Handler**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.formatBool = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
     var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
     var text = value ? "Yes" : "No";

     ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return text; });
  }
};
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanjones/4EZFJ/) as an example.

**Computed "Formatted" Value**

Since you're using the mapping plugin to build your entire viewModel, this may not be the best solution, but it's generally useful to use a computed to format other observable values.

```
viewModel.options.data.isActive.formatted = ko.computed(function(){
  return viewmodel.options.data.isActive ? "Yes" : "No";
});
```

**Override toJSON**

That said, if you really prefer to override your toJS/toJSON functions, you can override those methods on your view models.

```
viewModel.toJSON = function(){
  var copy = ko.toJS(this);
  copy.isActive = copy.isActive === "Yes" ? 1 : 0;
  return copy;
}
```

Here's a [great article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html) by Ryan Niemeyer that explains exactly how this is done.